# Converting Pixel distance to real world distance

Tags: opencv, distance

I am working with Opencv to calculate speed of moving objects, currently I am trying to calculate the speed based on 2 points I have marked on my image, I already know the distance of the two points in real world but do not know how to reference the distance of the points from pixels to meters, here is what I mean; suppose an object has moved 20pxof total marked distance how can I convert that to real life distance?

Here is the requested Image, the two points are the blue dots, in my country the white strip is almost always `3m` and the gap between them `4.5m` so the total distance there is about `12.5`

[image]

Comment: Show us a sample picture. It will depend if the object is moving left-right *across* your picture or front-back *into* your picture. It will also depend on the time between your frames.

Comment: I have added an image of my scene

Answer (score 0):

I think what your asking for is impossible with your setup.  A monocular setup in general forms a ray in the real world for every pixel in the image world.  This ray extends to infinity, so any point in the real world along this line, even hundreds or thousands or millions of meters in front of your camera, corresponds to this pixel.  A stereo setup would give you what you want.

Since you have somehow got the speed of the vehicles, you could use this to estimate the distance from a row of pixels to another row of pixels, since your road looks approximately perpendicular to your image plane.

But in general, without extra information than you're telling us, what you want to do is impossible in with a monocular (one camera) setup.